# Ros melodic install - unable to locate package ros-melodic-ros-base

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**EDIT:**

It seems like I messed up some settings for my static ip; new-installed Ubuntu now it works

**Old Text**

Hi,

im new to melodic (and ubuntu) but had success installing ros melodic on different machines so far.

Now, I want to install it on my raspberry pi 3b, where 18.04 (Server) is running so far.

I followed the installation [instructions](http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Ubuntu), but I get an error at 1.3 - "Set up your keys":

> gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.

sudo apt update then yields the following:

> Hit:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic InRelease
> Hit:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-updates InRelease
> Hit:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-backports InRelease
> Hit:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports bionic-security InRelease
> Get:5 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic InRelease [4680 B]
> Err:5 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic InRelease
> The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F42ED6FBAB17C654
> Reading package lists... Doneros-base
> W: GPG error: http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY F42ED6FBAB17C654
> E: The repository 'http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is not signed.
> N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
> N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

(Sorry for the formatting, dont know how to resolve this).

Finally, when i want to install:

> E: Unable to locate package ros-melodic-ros-base

I hope I've provided all needed information:)

Thanks for your help.
Robin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381631/ros-melodic-install---unable-to-locate-package-ros-melodic-ros-base/) by [robin_rob96](https://answers.ros.org/users/77028/robin_rob96/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2021-07-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-07-06**:
if you figured out what caused your problems, please post your solution as an answer and accept your own answer.

That way future readers would benefit from what you found out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I first installed Ubuntu on the pi, I followed a random tutorial for setting a static ip in my local network - I forgot about details. Turns out, this was what made the error; after a clean ubuntu install, my problems were gone.

---

Originally posted by [robin_rob96](https://answers.ros.org/users/77028/robin_rob96/) with karma: 46 on 2021-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0